# 301 Redirect to remove subdomain works on and off

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal, subdomain

Here is what I want to do:

```
travel.xx.com                             => xx.com/travel
travel.xx.com/fun                         => xx.com/fun
travel.xx.com/page.htm                    => xx.com/page.htm

health.xx.com                             => xx.com/health
health.xx.com/food                        => xx.com/food
health.xx.com/page2.htm                    => xx.com/page2.htm
```

Here is my htaccess rules:

RULE SET NUM 1:
//to convert subdomain.xx.com to xx.com/subdomain   and subdomain.xx.com/WHATEVER to xx.com/subdomain/WHATEVER

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^health.xx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xx.com/health/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^travel.xx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xx.com/travel/$1 [R=301,L]
```

RULE SET NUM 2: 
to convert xx.com/subdomain/WHATEVER to  xx.com/WHATEVER

```
RewriteRule ^(travel|health)(\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\&^\-\_\!\:\,\.\']+)?$ $3 [R=301,L]
```

Rule set number one and number two work fine separately. When I put them together, rule number 2 stops working and redirects to the root.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here or give me a solution for this?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you thing **RULE SET NUM 2** should be doing? Why are you discarding `/health/` or `/travel/` path in this rule?

Comment: In rule set num 1, I am removing the subdomain. but it adds the subdomain to the url while it should not add it to all patterns. look at the sample. In rule num 2, I am trying to remove it from some of the links with a specific pattern.

Comment: You are redirecting them permanently change [R=301,L] to [L,R=301]

Comment: In first rule you are redirecting `http://health.xx.com/foobar` to `http://xx.com/health/foobar`. Then in rule 2 you're redirecting `http://xx.com/health/foobar` to `http://xx.com/foobar`. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I understand I am redirecting them manually. Is [R=301,L] different from [L, R=301]?

Comment: Yes, but in Rule number one, I am also doing this: travel.xx.com                             => xx.com/travel which is needed. In the sample, you can see for some cases, subdomain should be moved into the link.

Comment: I actually add the subdomain to all of the urs and then remove it from some of them.

Comment: But is `http://xx.com/health/foobar` same as `http://xx.com/foobar`?

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of 3 rules shown you just need these 2 rules doing same thing**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(health|travel)\.(xx\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%2/%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(health|travel)\.(xx\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%2/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Make sure to keep this code before other rules.

Comment: No at work any more. Will test it tomorrow morning and let you know. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This one adds the subdomain to all of the urls. what rule 1 does. travel.xx.com                             => xx.com/travel
travel.xx.com/fun                         => xx.com/TRAVEL/fun
travel.xx.com/page.htm                    => xx.com/TRAVEL/page.htm         I want the second and third line has not subdomain in the url.

Comment: This one doesn't work at all. Can you explain your rules. I don't know what those %1 and %2 are.

Comment: Well if it doesn't work then explanations are of no use. Can you provide you latest .htaccess in question so that I can investigate.

Comment: Also provide some info like for what URL it didn't work and what error you got?